# How can I run Chrome from commandline after closing explorer.exe with taskkill?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

I have an old PC (I mean really old!) and it crashes every time I use Chrome.

So I came with a bright idea. Why not close Explorer and run Chrome at the same same time using taskkill through a batch file.

So I placed chrome.exe along with the batch file on my desktop. Now I have lost the .bat file but I know it didn't work. It was able to stop Windows Explorer but was unable to run Chrome. I am relatively new to cmd so I vaguely remember the code. It was like:

```
taskkill explorer.exe
run chrome.exe
```

Comment: just run explorer.exe to bring back the desktop. `%userprofile%\desktop\batchFile.bat" to if you just want to run that bat... But, most interesting is that you would worry about the overhead of explorer.exe and expect Chrome to run half decent?

Comment: I have knowledge on how to run the explorer once I close it. However, what I want to know is that can chrome run without explorer or not and if yes, then how.

Comment: Just call chrome.exe from the command prompt,  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe` would work on x64

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want:

```
taskkill /f /Im explorer.EXE
Start chrome.exe
```

What this will do is force explorer.EXE to quit, then start chrome.EXE (which is the chrome application file. )